# Is Dual table Oracle managed tablespace or User managed table space

Tags: database, oracle

I have been trying to search which tablespace does the DUAL table belong to in Oracle database.
Either it belongs to Oracle managed tablespace or User managed table space.

I ran the following query to see the tablespace but it did not help:

```
select tablespace_name from all_tables where owner='USR00' and table_name='dual';
```

Please suggest.

PS: I understand DUAL table is a dummy table.

Comment: The table you're looking for is named `'DUAL'`, not `'dual'`. Also, you don't own it.All objects in Oracle default to UPPER_CASE unless you specifically quote them (e.g. `CREATE TABLE "lowercase_name"...`). Worse, if you *do* quote a name to make it non-upper-case you'll have to quote it every time you use it, forever. Seriously - do not create objects with quoted names. Your colleagues will curse your name, your family will look askance at you, your dog will bite you, and, eventually, you'll dissipate yourself with drink, women, and comic books and die too young. Don't ask me how I know...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DUAL` is a SYS-owned table.

```
SQL> select owner, tablespace_name from all_tables where table_name = 'DUAL';

OWNER                          TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
SYS                            SYSTEM

SQL>
```

What you see and use is a **public synonym**, i.e. you don't "own" it, so your `owner='USR00'` couldn't return anything.

```
SQL> select owner, synonym_name, table_owner, table_name from all_synonyms where synonym_name = 'DUAL';

OWNER      SYNONYM_NAME TABLE_OWNER  TABLE_NAME
---------- ------------ ------------ ----------
PUBLIC     DUAL         SYS          DUAL

SQL>
```

Comment: So, what category should we put in Oracle managed tablespaces or User managed tablespaces.

Comment: What do you think (if it is owned by SYS)?

Comment: SYS (and SYSTEM) "own" an Oracle database.

Comment: SYS.USER_TABLES describes all tables in the database that are owned by the current user. According to Oracle docs https://docs.oracle.com/database/timesten-18.1/TTSYS/systemtables.htm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216455/discussion-between-learningtocode-and-littlefoot).